# LS1 - ticking slapping noise w video

Tags: engine, chevrolet, troubleshooting, noise, ls1

So I'm trying to identify what may be the cause of this ticking noise.
I listened to all the LS1 ticking and knocking videos on YouTube but none are similar to mine.

It sort of sounds like when you hold a metal pen between two fingers and you tap it against a metal table. Best way for the to describe it. Maybe the rods or something.

[**Here is the video**](https://youtu.be/8GwIP8aN1Xs)

You can hear it best at 0:05 and 0:22. The sound seems to be coming from the backside of the engine (closer to firewall).

It would be great if I could get some thoughts on what it could be, maybe what I can do about it as well.

Comment: Can you isolate where the sound is coming from with a stethoscope? How's the oil level? condition? pressure?

Comment: That sounds like lifter tick. Does it change with engine speed?

Comment: The oil level is good.  I dont have a stethoscope. I'll connect obd2 reader to check oil pressure. what values am i looking for on an LS1 ? Regards to  change with speed ill rev it when it warms up.

Comment: I bought an obd2 reader and it threw a P0300, could a misfire cause a tapping noise like that ?

Comment: the misfire might be because of the tapping noise if theres a loose rocker or a lifter is collapsed. use a long screw driver as a stethoscope if you can't find one locally.

Answer (score 1):

I have an LS2 that makes a sound similar to that sound but it was an upper valve tap so i put some Seafoam in the oil before the oil change and now the sound is gone. It also could be the exhaust manifold bolts are broken causing a noise that sounds like an upper valve tap. Speaking form experience it's probably the manifold bolts are broken. Good luck diagnosing the issue. Hope my answer helped.